# p:datatable sort language with responsive reflow = "true"

Tags: sorting, jsf, primefaces, datatable

How can I change the language for Sorting on PF DataTable component with reflow = "true" (so responsive Datatable)?

The problem is that on mobile screen, we can sort data from auto-generated dropdown where we have our sort options, see picture bellow. How can I change the language for this dropdown?
[image]

I'm using PF 6.0.

Comment: Is it about the 'Ascending' part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never ran into this or used it, but I know the source is open. So I went to the [javascript file for the datatable](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/datatable/datatable.js). There I searched for 'Ascending' and via `this.ascMessage`, I ended up on [line 170](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/datatable/datatable.js#L170) where `'datatable.sort.ASC'` is used as a key.

This in turn points to [line 619 in core.js](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/core/core.js#L619)

```
getAriaLabel: function(key) {
        var ariaLocaleSettings = this.getLocaleSettings()['aria'];
        return (ariaLocaleSettings&&ariaLocaleSettings[key]) ? ariaLocaleSettings[key] : PrimeFaces.locales['en_US']['aria'][key];
},
```

Where you can see the normal PrimeFaces locale functionality is used.

So using your [own locale](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/wiki/Locales) and overriding this part in it, like in the [default locale](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/core/core.js#L668)

```
aria: {
    'paginator.PAGE': 'Page {0}',
    'calendar.BUTTON': 'Show Calendar',
    'datatable.sort.ASC': 'activate to sort column ascending',
    'datatable.sort.DESC': 'activate to sort column descending',
    'columntoggler.CLOSE': 'Close'
}
```

Will solve your issue I would expect

Comment: this solution is not working. It only adapts the aria labels. The labels in the page are not changed. The answer of Dominik is the only correct one... I have been debugging in the DataRenderer class as mentioned by Dominik and it does use the messages.properties. Adding the three property values there makes the labels change... Please refer to the answer of Dominik to avoid confusion in the future. Tnx ;-)

Comment: What is your PF version. Might very well be that this changed in between my answer and the other one.

Comment: Now using 6.1.2. In another project using 6.0.0 I checked the DataTableRenderer and there the code is the same (using MessageFactory.getMessage also). Probably then 5.X...

Comment: @FabiYo: Thanks for the clarification. I'll check out the old code and add that to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The intended way to do this is to define the following properties in your resource files (see [Messages.properties](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/tree/master/src/main/resources/org/primefaces))

```
primefaces.datatable.SORT_LABEL = Sort
primefaces.datatable.SORT_ASC = Ascending
primefaces.datatable.SORT_DESC = Descending
```

You can see this when you look at the [DatatableRender](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/b1d7673fecf7e8f44008bf1580982590a5fbc3aa/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/datatable/DataTableRenderer.java#L1660) of primefaces.

Notice i18n is done in different ways in primefaces. Some components like calendar or schedule must be translated via javascript. See [here](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/wiki/Locales)

Comment: What do you mean by 'intended way'? I don't see any reason in the current PrimeFaces code that this would work the way you describe. It still is as in the answer above. Care to elaborate why you think your answer is good (I'm not saying it is wrong, just looking for confirmation in the source)

Comment: I added some more information to my answer. I do not know if your solution works, but it is accepted, so probably. I just wonder because all this aria stuff is normally used for accessibilty. This is also why the text is "activate to sort column ascending" is such a long text and not just "ascending"

Comment: True. I'm going to need to used this in the not so distant future so I'll investigate more.

Comment: and put <message-bundle>messages</message-bundle> on your faces-config file